# Multi-threading condition, start thread on the second iteration?

Tags: python, multithreading

**[Challenge]:**

I have two threads, the first one is *some_signal* and the second one is *post_proccesing*.

For the first iteration, I would like to run, *post_proccesing* after *some_signal*.

And after the first iteration.
I would like to start *post_proccesing* thread, so *post_proccesing* would use *some_signal* data from the previous loop.

**[Pseudocode]:**

- First iteration:

  1. some_signal
  2. post_proccesing
- Second iteration:

  1. start treading
  2. some_signal and post_proccesing[some_signal-1]

**[My Attempt]:**

I have tried to implement it using the following way, but I'm not entirely sure,if I've done it correctly:

```
import threading

def some_signal():
    print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Get signal'

def post_proccesing():
    print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Process the signa;'

t = threading.Thread(name='post_proccesing', target=post_proccesing)
w = threading.Thread(name='some_signal', target=some_signal)

flag = 0;
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=some_signal) # use default name

    if flag == 0:
        some_signal() # use default name
        flag  = flag + 1;
    else:
        w = threading.Thread(target=post_proccesing) # use default name
    w.start()
    t.start()
```

Comment: Read about [condition-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects)

Comment: Side note: you should upgrade to python 3.X because 2.X will be discontinued soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you can implement logic based on `i` (your iteration count). Maybe something like this would suit you (I'm not sure what intent you have with `flag` so I removed it):

```
import threading

def some_signal():
    print(threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Get signal')

def post_proccesing():
    print(threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Process the signa;')

for i in range(5):
    if i: # means i > 0 because 0 -> False
        t = threading.Thread(target=some_signal) # use default name
        # removed 'else' statement because you need to have a 'w' variable for your call to 'w.start()'
        w = threading.Thread(target=post_proccesing) # use default name
        t.start()
        w.start()
    else: # case where i == 0 -> first iteration
        some_signal()
        post_proccesing()
```

Output:

```
MainThread Get signal
MainThread Process the signa;
Thread-1 Get signal
Thread-2 Process the signa;
Thread-3 Get signal
Thread-4 Process the signa;
Thread-5 Get signal
Thread-6 Process the signa;
Thread-7 Get signal
Thread-8 Process the signa;
```